# Need help writing htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess

Currently my localhost URL is like `localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&action=contacts`

Now I want to write a rule so that when I go to above url it just rewrite the url like `localhost/apnaujjain/contacts.html`

See it should convert `.php` into `.html` without affect page content.

Until now I've tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php?page_id=1$&action=2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $2.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in `/apnaujjain/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apnaujjain/

# redirect localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&action=contacts to
# localhost/apnaujjain/1/contacts.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but page_id is also change and its not working on localhost . Let me try on server but thanks and how to add dynamic page_id like action

Comment: still not working when I go to localhost/apnaujjain/index.php then it redirect me to localhost/index.html and when I go to inner pages it is not changing url. I am really very bad in regular expression, please help.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I've changed my url and now its http://localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?action=important_contacts&page_id=2, I just changed the parameters position as I only need action parameter in url rewrite not page id, so please now suggest me exact rule.

Comment: yes thats ok but actually page id will also change as we go to other pages thats why I just need to put action name as .html extension check this live url http://www.apnaujjain.com/page.php?page_id=2&action=important_contacts

Comment: Ok I've changed my url as previous and now it looks like localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=4&action=apnaujjain and now I need to convert it like localhost/apnaujjain/page_id/action, please reply as soon as possible, thanks

Comment: thanks its working except it redirects to page as html but all my css and js not applying on page, I've broke it like header and footer and include in all pages

Comment: Hello Anubhava, Your htaccess is working fine and I modified it for three variables and url is ok but I am unable to get variable by name, the url is like localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/apnaujjain/1/1/contacts.html and its working fine but I am unable to get album id. Can you suggest me what I am doing wrong here...thanks

Comment: Actually that URL will need another set of rules. I suggest opening a new question so that I can answer it there.